# java imported resource names

Tags: import, jar, module, coding-style

I'm somewhat new to the realm of programming where someone has already written what you need, and your job is to bundle it up under a simple class that calls the other person's functions, and the typical uses of import strike me as extremely odd.

As an example, I'm using an open-source spell checking jar called jazzy-core.jar. Why do I type

```
import com.swabunga.spell.engine.spellDictionaryHashMap;
```

to use some piece of this jar? I was expecting something more like

```
import jazzy-core.spellDictionaryHashMap;
```

or even just

```
import jazzy-core;
```

Why are all of those words (com, swabunga, etc) necessary, what do they mean, and why is none of them "jazzy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `import` doesn't mean that you actually include the jar in your application. The jar file could have a completely different name and therefore specifying the jar file's name in the import statement wouldn't be feasible. Instead the `import` allows you to reference the `spellDictionaryHashMap` without specifying its fully qualified name. That is you can write stuff like

```
spellDictionaryHashMap map = new spellDictionaryHashMap();
```

instead of

```
com.swabunga.spell.engine.spellDictionaryHashMap map = new com.swabunga.spell.engine.spellDictionaryHashMap();
```

Classes and interfaces in Java are organized in packages (which have nothing to do with jar files) and this particular class is in the package `com.swabunga.spell.engine`.